# Can a function using a global variable use the variable's value from when the function was declared rather than when it was called?

Tags: python

Here is a very simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
x = 3
def f():
     print(x)
x = 5
f() #f prints 5 but I want it to print 3.
```

Is there a way, when declaring the function, to turn `x` into a constant that points somewhere other than the global variable `x`? I can't provide arguments to the function.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Why does `x` need to be reassigned before it's used?

Comment: This violates the principle of least surprise. I'd suggest refactoring your code.

Comment: Why not just use another variable you wont change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common trick (you usually see it in `lambda` expressions that want to bind a particular value within a loop):

```
x = 3
def f(x=x):
     print(x)
x = 5
f()  # prints 3
```

The trick is that default parameter values are evaluated at the time of function definition, so in the expression `x=x`, the `x` on the right hand side is evaluated (producing the value 3) and then stored as the default value of the `x` parameter in the function (which shadows the `x` in the outer scope).

You could equivalently write:

```
x = 3
def f(n=x):
     print(n)
x = 5
f()  # prints 3
```

which has the same result, but doesn't shadow the `x` variable.

Comment: "I can't provide arguments to the function" - OP. Not sure if kwargs count or not though...

Comment: I expect they just mean they can't provide arguments at the time the function is called (which this satisfies).

Comment: Sure, fair enough @Samwise.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you seem to want `x` to hold two values *simultaneously* - which is what complex data structures are for. A `list` would work fine, or a `dict`:

```
>>> x = [3]
>>> def f():
...     print(x[0]) # always refers to first element. Functionally constant.
... 
>>> x.append(5)
>>> f()
3
>>>
```

However, it sounds like you really have an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem, where you're asking about your solution instead of your actual problem. Go back to your code and check if this seems to be the case. If so, we might be able to point you towards a better way of solving your real issue.